# bind9, named not accessible over local network behind router ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bind, named-conf

i have a zte F6600R router from my isp provider with following configuration

```
DHCP SERVER : ON
LAN IP ADDR : 192.168.1.1
SUBNET MASK : 255.255.255.0
DHCP start IP : 192.168.1.10
DHCP end IP : 192.168.1.250
ISP DNS : OFF
PRIMARY DNS : 8.8.8.8 // working internet fine
SECONDARY DNS: 8.8.4.4 // working internet fine
LEASE TIME MODE: CUSTOM
CUSTOM LEASE TIME : 86400
```

following bind configuration:

> named.conf

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
//include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

following

> named.conf.local

```
zone "webtrade.dark" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/forward.webtrade.dark";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/reverse.webtrade.dark";
};
```

following

> named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    listen-on { any; };
    allow-query { any; };
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };

    dnssec-validation auto;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

following

> forward.webtrade.dark

```
$TTL    14400
@   IN  SOA blastwave.webtrade.dark. root.blastwave.webtrade.dark. (
                  7     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  blastwave.webtrade.dark.
blastwave   IN  A   192.168.1.12
www IN  A   192.168.1.12
@   IN  AAAA    ::1
```

following

> reverse.webtrade.dark

```
$TTL    14400
@   IN  SOA blastwave.webtrade.dark. root.blastwave.webtrade.dark. (
                  7     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  blastwave.webtrade.dark.
blastwave   IN  A   192.168.1.12
12  IN  PTR blastwave.webtrade.dark.
```

in named status all works fine zones loaded dig ok with authority over webtrade.dark, dig on reverse with 1 answer and 0 authority

following

> /etc/resolv.conf

```
search webtrade.dark
nameserver 192.168.1.12
```

following

> /etc/default/named

```
RESOLVCONF=no
OPTIONS="-u bind -4"
```

> hostname --fqdn => blastwave

haven't touched */etc/hosts* file

> installed apache2 on the dns server machine

defined domain is not accessible by the other devices on the network pc phone etc.
what do i miss? please help

> named status

[image: status of bind]

```
netstat -pnltu | grep ':53'
```

[image: status ip pid port]

Comment: also port 53 opened and no other pid using them but named

Comment: How would other devices on your network know about this DNS server of yours? Your modem controls DHCP and sets client DNS to Google's DNS servers..

Comment: In other words i need to make DHCP server too from my dns server? so my server assign ip s to other devices? and reference it into the router / modem? router had other dns s something like 192.168.x.x or something changes lost. Another edit server is accessible by its ip address locally of course

Comment: I would set IP address of your DNS server as DNS server in your router DHCP settings

Comment: not working setting ip in router DHCP settings

Comment: NOTE completely disabled router DHCP server same ip's assigned

Comment: The question is what DNS server address your clients (phones, PCs) are using/getting. For your setup to work they need to have 192.168.1.12 set as their DNS..

Comment: As per my PC using win7 aleardy set the dns server still not working. i Think the problem is server side. Because i followed a tutorial once and it worked for a few times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151056/discussion-between-andrei-claudiu-viziru-and-peter-zhabin).

Comment: You have to configure your clients to use your DNS server as DNS server. You can do that on the clients, or in the dhcp setup. However, this question is clearly outside the scope of serverfault.

Comment: Yes windows host and router ip already been configured with the dns defined server